# How to solve this system of differential equations in a complex variable?

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I would like to solve the system:
$$
\begin{array}{rclr}
\frac{d}{dz} u & = & \frac{\alpha}{z^k} u & +  v \\
\frac{d}{dz} v & = & &   \frac{\alpha}{z^k} v
\end{array}
$$
where $\alpha$ is a complex constant and $k$ is a positive integer.  Of course $v$ is given by $C\exp(\alpha z^{-k+1}/(-k+1))$ (or $z^\alpha$ when $k = 1$).  What is $u$ though?  If there's no very explicit solution, is it a famous special function?

Answer (score 0):

Since $v = C_1 \exp(\alpha z^{-k+1}/(-k+1))$ for any constant $C_1$ and $k \neq 1$, we need to find a solution of
$$
\frac{d}{dz} u  =  \frac{\alpha}{z^k} u + C_1 \exp(\alpha z^{-k+1}/(-k+1)).
$$
First, we find a solution of the corresponding homogeneous problem
$$
\frac{d}{dz} u_0  =  \frac{\alpha}{z^k} u_0.
$$
We have (exactly like $v$)
$$
u_0 = C \exp(\alpha z^{-k+1}/(-k+1)).
$$
Now we use the method of variation of constants and conclude that
$$
\frac{d}{dz}C = C_1.
$$
Hence, 
$C(z) = C_1 z + C_2$, and therefore
$$
u = (C_1 z + C_2) \exp(\alpha z^{-k+1}/(-k+1)).
$$